# How to recover base64 encoded text from its hash and salt in vb?

Tags: c#, vb.net, hash, passwords

I have stored passwords as hash and salt, encrypted with base64. Now I want to recover original password from that hash and salt. How? I am using vb.net in MS Visual Studio, but I am comfortable with C#, too.

Comment: Nice, teaching to hack a database...

Comment: The very purpose of hashing is to be a one way road: _**You cannot decrypt it**_, and you are not supposed to do so either! If you want to verify a password (login) then you just create a new hash (with the same salt) from the inputted login credentials and compare that to the stored hash, like so: `If hash(input, storedsalt) = storedhash Then`

Comment: And don't even think of switching to regular encryption! Doing so would make your product very _**unsafe**_, and in 2017 nobody should even consider doing such a thing.

Comment: 1) Search for "8ZtInClXe1Q" on YouTube, 2) Learn to create a login against Google, Facebook, Microsoft Live, ...

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up several things. First of all you shouldn't *encrypt* passwords. Instead you should *hash* them. Base64-encoding is neither of both.

A base64-encoded string may not be directly human-readable, but it can be very easily be converted back to cleartext. So it's not safe at all.

Have a look at this comprehensive article to learn more about password hashing:
https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm